# Jython webapp performance

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, jython

I'm currently building a Jython web app but am concerned about Jython application performance.  I take some comfort in that any compute intensive tasks I can write in a separate Java jar and invoke them from Jython.  Has anyone had problems doing this, or forsee issues with such a setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a nice comparison here: http://blog.dhananjaynene.com/2008/07/performance-comparison-c-java-python-ruby-jython-jruby-groovy/

Jython is slower, but depending on what you want to do, that may not be a big problem. I use Jython primarily for allowing me to debug the application on the fly, and it works great for this.

Answer (score 1):

As always, I would put something together (a prototype etc.) and measure it. That's the *only* way you're going to get a meaningful answer, I believe.